# iOS exception EXC_GUARD

Tags: objective-c, ios, testflight

I had a crash on an iPhone 4 with an exception type of EXC_GUARD. I can't find any information on this particular exception via google (only 1 result) or on stackoverflow. What is it?

```
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-10-24 14:29:53.740 -0700
OS Version:      iOS 6.0 (10A403)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_GUARD
Exception Codes: 0x0000000100000010, 0x08fd4dbfade2dead
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  MAIN  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32f25294 close + 8
1   Twine                           0x00230b8e close_file + 10
2   Twine                           0x00218774 -[TFAirTrafficController startSession] + 752
3   Twine                           0x002169fa +[TestFlight takeOff:] + 122
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

https://devforums.apple.com/message/713606

It's a bug in TestFlight causing a close on a duff file handle. This causes that crash.

Comment: This has been fixed in v1.2beta2

Comment: Would have been better had this not been in one of my live apps!

Comment: Annoying wasn't it :-). We've moved to from TestFlight now anyway. Too many crashes like this, coupled with just poor user experience.

Comment: I I get it right, that means that after updating to iOS6, apps using the testflight sdk began to crash randomly at launch. Ouch.

Comment: This bug has been in there since September. Why isn't the beta out as final by now?! This bug is a real problem and I don't want to use the beta version.

Comment: What now? I'm using TestFlight 1.2.6 and this exact crash still happens here! Really annoying :(

Comment: On iOS 7, this could also be occurring if you try to close fd 0.