# App crashes on [TestFlight takeOff:@""] in iOS 6.1.2

Tags: iphone, ios, testflight

I have TestFlight SDK integrated into my iOS app. In iOS 6.1.2, sometimes the app crashes for the first-time app launch at TestFlight's -takeOff: method.

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

#ifdef TESTING
    [TestFlight takeOff:@"MY_TESTFLIGHT_TEAM_TOKEN"];
    [TestFlight setDeviceIdentifier:[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]];
#endif

// Override point for customization after application launch.
ProductListViewController *products=[[ProductListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProductListViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:products];
[products release];

navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

self.rootViewController = navigationController;
[self.window setRootViewController:rootViewController];

[navigationController release];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Feel free to show takeOff method as well :)

Comment: Can you provide any error output?

Comment: Is that your secret TestFlight key that you just posted?

Comment: `uniqueIdentifier` is deprecated after iOS 5.0. Using it will generally get your app rejected. In 6.0 you'll have to use `advertisingIdentifier`.

Comment: It is not giving any logs on crash. It just raises an exception EXC_???(12)(code=15, subcode=0xade2dead)
@nevanking it is the key for a sample app i created :) Thanks - will change to advertisingIdentifier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in the Testflight SDK. They ask you to update to the latest beta version.

See [iOS exception EXC_GUARD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058329/ios-exception-exc-guard)

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Resolved the crash by updating to TestFlight SDK 1.2

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you've forgotten to include the TestFlight SDK folder properly?

Comment: Checked that and it looks good. It crashes only sometimes and that too in iOS 6.1.2 and for the first launch.